# Else not executing

Tags: if-statement

login.php

```
$username = @mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_username']);

if($username == ""){
echo'<span><a href="#" style="text-transform: capitalize;" role="button"    
class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></span> 
</li>
<li>

</li>';
}
else{
echo '<li><a href="#" style="text-transform: capitalize;" role="button"   
class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-user"   
style="color:white; margin-right:8px;"></i>Welcome <span 
style="color:#71F9FE; font-weight:bold;">'.$username.'</span> 

<a href="logout.php"style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" 
style="margin-right:5px;"></i>iLogout</a>

</li>';  


}?>
```

When i am trying to login the else part in sot executing  the same code i used in my admin login but there it is working perfectly.... i don't understand why my else part is not working ....

Comment: Can you add `echo $username;` after the first line to see what `$username` contains.

Comment: ya it is displaying database username... not login username..

Comment: You're testing if the username is empty `if($username=="")` and if it's never empty, the `else` will never be reached.